# Connecting to mongoHQ with mongojs on heroku

Tags: node.js, mongodb, heroku, mongohq, mongojs

I am trying to connect to mongoHQ from my node.js app. 
Here is the code I am using:

```
 var databaseUrl = "mongodb://fishcuss:MyPassword@alex.mongohq.com:10015/app9759558"
 var collections = ["users"]
 var db = require("mongojs").connect(databaseUrl, collections);


 exports.register = function(req, res){
   console.log("Register hit")
   var user = req.body;
   db.users.findOne({username:user.username}, function(err, users) {
     console.log(err)
     console.log(users);
     if( err || users) {
         res.statusCode = 500;
         res.end();
     }
     else {
         console.log("Inserting new user")
         user._id = uuid.v4();
         user.lists = [];
         db.users.insert(user,{},function(){
             req.session.user=user
             res.write(JSON.stringify(user), 'UTF-8');
             res.statusCode = 200;
             res.end();
         })
     } ;
 });
};
```

However I seem to get this error

```
{ [MongoError: auth fails] name: 'MongoError', errmsg: 'auth fails', ok: 0 }
```

Which leads me to believe that I am missing something in my connection. Anyone have a hint as to what that might be?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why your code doesn't work but I believe you need to authenticate AFTER opening a connection.

I also use Heroku + MongoLAB, and I use the [mongo-db-native](https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native) driver. That combination seems to work pretty well.

Check out what I do below:

```
var mongodb = require('mongodb');
mongo_client = new mongodb.Db(mongo_db_name, new mongodb.Server(mongo_url, mongo_port), {safe:true});

mongo_client.open(function(err, p_client) {

    if (err)
        console.warn("MONGO ERROR:" + err.message);

    p_client.authenticate(mongo_db_username,mongo_db_password,{},function(err,success){
        if (err) {
            console.warn("MONGO ERROR: unauthorized "+ err.message);

        } else {
            console.log("MONGO Authorized");
            mongo_messages_collection = new mongodb.Collection(p_client, 'messages');
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably, the username/password you are using are not matching. If you are unsure, create a new user on the mongohq console and use those credentials.